# Get Country,City name from IPAddress

Tags: asp.net, geolocation, trace

can we trace the user geographical location in asp.net ,
I know we can get the user IP address or **`ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")`**
but  my need is to check the visitors by city name so can my client use this data for his business

Comment: I am not .net guy, I am actually a PHP dev but this is quite universal across board. Yes, you can get A country and A city, but as to whether it is your users COUNTRY and CITY....well it is unlikely to be your users city since most ISPs do not hold their exchanges in the same city as the user...but you have a good chance with country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment:

> I am not .net guy, I am actually a PHP dev but this is quite universal
>   across board. Yes, you can get A country and A city, but as to whether
>   it is your users COUNTRY and CITY....well it is unlikely to be your
>   users city since most ISPs do not hold their exchanges in the same
>   city as the user...but you have a good chance with country.

But I thought I would elaborate a bit.

The country, especially if they are like me and using an encrypted proxy, won't be of any help to you, however services like cloudflare will give you the users IP country in HTTP headers, and it's free. Better than spending £200 a month on getting nothing but false positives from dedicated services.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked on asp.net forum and it was answered using a good example.

Reference : [Link](http://forums.asp.net/post/3072924.aspx)

> How do you expect to do that?  My IP is assigned by an ISP located 300
>   miles from me.  My web host is in North Carolina, a 16 hour drive
>   away.  My cellular link in my notebook has an IP issued from New
>   Jersey.  It's been two decades since the last time I was in New
>   Jersey.   [1](http://forums.asp.net/post/3072924.aspx): http://forums.asp.net/post/3072924.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am probably really late answering this, but I recently worked on this project because I needed it myself. so maybe it might help someone out there.

http://iplookup.tk/service/iplookup/{YOUR IP ADDRESS}

NB: depending on the content-type of your request the result can either be in Json or XML. by default its xml